# What is a nerf?

Tags: star-wars, terminology

In the classic scene, Princess Leia slams Han Solo by calling him a

> stuck up, half-witted, scruffy-looking nerf herder

While clearly this cuts Han to the bone, I'm curious what this actually means.

Presumably it is someone who herds "nerfs" for a living, but what is a nerf? Is there anything particularly offensive about those who herd nerfs?

Comment: Ha! I always thought it was, *"scruffy **nerve hurter**"* :) But [you're right](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Empire-Strikes-Back.html).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm voting to close as general reference. "Nerf" Wookiepedia page is the first result on Google search for "star wars What is a nerf?"; more importantly "Nerf Herder" Wikipedia page is #4 result on the same search and #2 result on "nerf herder" google search.

Comment: @DVK: you're right, but I'm just amazed that I completely misheard it (and so voted it up). All these years...

Comment: @DVK According to this [meta](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/how-have-we-been-using-the-general-reference-close-reason), it seems consensus has been that wookiepedia does not count for "general reference".  Searching for "nerf herder" or "what is a nerf" does not result in wikipedia giving relevant information (first gives a band, and second gives info on the foam toys).

Comment: @Beofett - "what is a nerf herder star wars": result #4 is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Wars_creatures (which includes a Nerf). Wikipedia is general reference. And while Wookiepedia isn't a general reference per se, having a definition of the term show up as #1 Google result is more of a general reference than not, IMHO.

Comment: @DVK Google for "what is a nerf" and "nerf herder" gives the band's page and the foam toys.  Searching within wikipedia for "what is a nerf" or "nerf herder" gives the same results. While clearly it can be found in wikipedia, it appears that only works if you add additional key words. I don't think my searches were entirely unreasonable, and I think there's a difference between "exists somewhere on wikipedia" and "easily found" or "general reference".

Comment: [Here's another relevant meta discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/328/how-should-we-handle-questions-that-are-easily-answered-by-wikipedia/330#330). Based on this chart, I would say Yes, No, Interesting => answer the question.

Comment: @Wikis I'd go for Yes, Yes (could be improved) as you did with your excellent picture.

Comment: [Additional relevant meta discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/690/1359).

Comment: The Wikipedia article for “nerf herder” does answer the question reasonably clearly (it's about a band but has a section on [the origin of the name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerf_herder#Origin_of_band_name)), with a link to the Star Wars Wiki. There is also an entry for [Nerf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerf_%28disambiguation%29).

Comment: @Gilles I have to admit it did not occur to me to read the entire article on the band in the hopes of finding an explanation as to what a "nerf" is. Based upon the various meta conversations linked here in comments, and the fact that the best arguments for it being "general reference" either involve additional search terms or reading articles that are at best tangentially related, I am respectfully voting to reopen this.

Comment: @Beofett The only parts of the “nerf article” article I read were the introduction saying it was a band, the table of contents, and the section on the origin of the name.

Comment: @Gilles and I stopped at "Nerf Herder is a punk band". Regardless of whether you read the article or skimmed it, you pursued what is clearly a resource that is only tangentially related in the hopes that it would lead you to more information. If the assumption on "general reference" is that anything that can be found by sifting through multiple articles on Wikipedia is off topic, rather than being the obvious result of searching for the question, our criteria for "general reference" should be updated.

Comment: @DVK ah, the irony of coming across a post of mine that you voted to close as GR :)

Comment: @Beofett - Just because I don't like the rules doesn't mean I don't follow them. This fit the at-the-time in effect GR definition based on what my above comment said (and my at the time understanding of the rules). That said, I'm glad this is unclosed!

Comment: @DVK Oh, I know, and I didn't intend this as any sort of criticism (retroactive or otherwise).  Merely a "ha! I forgot I had a question that was closed as GR... and look! DVK was the first to suggest closing it!" :)

Comment: The only thing that "cuts" him is his objection to being called scruffy looking.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's an animal not unlike a buffalo in appearance. They are an *"antlered, herbivorous mammal found all across the galaxy."*

[image: Nerf, with herder]

[Source: Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Nerf).