# How many languages can Han Solo understand?

Tags: star-wars

We know that Han can understand Shyriiwook and Huttese, plus at least one dialect of binary, plus galactic Common of course, so that's at least four.  What other languages can he understand, if any?

I'll take any level of canonicity

Comment: While I don't think it's worthy of a DV or Close vote, I don't think this question is likely to produce very good answers, as it's most likely "We don't know", or a litany of short answers

Comment: I disagree -- I bet that it's actually spelled out in one of the novels.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On screen, we see him respond appropriately to

Language (Speaker; Movie)

1. Basic (assorted humans)
2. Shyriiwook (Chewbacca; ANH, ESB, RotJ)
3. Rhodese (Greedo; ANH)
4. Binary (one of his droids; ESB)
5. Huttese (Jabba the Hutt; RotJ)

Less canonical languages:

1. Trader's Argot is from the AC Crispin *Han Solo Trilogy* (novels).
2. Illodian is from Cube-McDowell's *Tyrant's Test*

Properly, Trader's Argot isn't actually a language, but a means of obfuscation of Basic by integrating borrowed terms and grammar. Still, it's a distinct manner of speaking that he clearly understands.

Comment: I think this is a better answer than mine, @zipquincy. This shows research and original material, very well thought through. Mine is just a copy / paste.

Comment: Quite the contrary to his on-screen persona - the guy is a certifiable genius.  He can fly AND repair his ship, great marksman, understands a multitude of languages - including the Wookie language which is obviously extremely subtle...genius.

Answer (score 14):

Per [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Han_Solo#Personality_and_traits), Han Solo understands:

1. Basic (native) (and speaks)
2. Selonian (and speaks)
3. Shyriiwook
4. Trader's argot
5. Rodese
6. Illodian
7. Huttese

Not bad for a [scruffy nerf herder](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9154/what-is-a-nerf).